# reST to Latex to PDF

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pdflatex, restructuredtext

I was able to generate the latex output from reST using **make latex** command of Sphinx/Python. It generated the required latex files under latex directory. I am not sure on what I need to do for creating the PDF from latex. Can someone help me on what should i do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an explanation of how to do it [here](http://mintaka.sdsu.edu/GF/bibliog/latex/LaTeXtoPDF.html).

Short story: use pdflatex.  All your images must be in .eps format.

You can get pdflatex [here](http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/). Edit: looks like it's a site for only pdftex.

I seem to recall [MiXTeX](http://www.miktex.org/2.9/setup) has the whole toolchain for windows users.  And it comes with all the binaries, including pdflatex.

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm.